# Using mongoDB how can i prevent someone from using the same username as someone else?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a form where a user is supposed to put in there nickname, the issue is I need the nickname to be unique, in that no one else should be able to make there nickname the same as someone elses. Is there a fix for this using only mongoDB and not mongoose?

```js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var PORT = 3332;

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/gtra", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open", function(cb) {
  console.log("connection established");
});

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  var name = req.body.pickname;
  var data = {
    nickname: name
  };
  db.collection("dat").insertOne(data, function(err, coll) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("rec estab");
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("server is up and running using port " + PORT);
});
```

Comment: Did you check my  answer?

Comment: just did, and it worked thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if there is already a username in the collection, if exists you can throw exception.

```js
app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  var data = {
    nickname: req.body.pickname
  };

  db.collection("dat").findOne({ nickname: data.nickname }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (doc) {
      return res.status(400).send("Nickname already taken"); //or throw whatever you want
    } else {
      db.collection("dat").insertOne(data, function(err, coll) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("rec estab");
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Another option is creating a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the nickname field.

```
db.users.createIndex( { "nickname": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Change users to your collection name.